Why doesn't Vader grab the second ship in the Obi-Wan Kenobi TV series?
In Part V of the Obi-Wan Kenobi TV series, Vader grabs the first ship that is taking off instead of the second ship. It's safe to assume that Vader is too tired to grab the second ship after the first one takes off, but why did he grab the first ship at all?
Shouldn't Vader be able to sense Obi-Wan's presence on the second ship, and know that the first ship was just a decoy?

I assume it's a whole "I sense him in that direction" kinda deal. He was in the right direction, but the distance was a little off

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264472/what-was-piloting-the-decoy-ship https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264422/extreme-use-of-the-force-by-vader-in-obi-wan-kenobi-tv-series

It's just my opinion but I think he temporarily exhausted himself bringing down the first ship. That and the second ship had a bit more momentum going than the decoy.

@MrInfinity My question is more directed at Vader's ability to use force sense.

Ah. Well you see a ship you expect to see taking off. Why waste the time and concentration to check for life.
